# Firestore addSnapshotListener doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Literally, it doesn't WORK.
There's no error, but it doesn't start networking with the server.

Weird thing is that the previous version of this app had worked well. There's no difference on this code with the prev version..

I think the code is just fine, but there would be another issue I can't figure out...

```
class FeedFragment : Fragment() {
    var firestore : FirebaseFirestore? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        var feedView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false)
        feedView.feed_recycler_view?.adapter = FeedRecyclerViewAdapter()
        feedView.feed_recycler_view?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2)

        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        if (firestore == null) Log.d("firestore", "doesnt work")
        else {
            Log.d("print", firestore.toString())
            // it throws the instance properly
        }
        return feedView
    }

    inner class FeedRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
        var contentDTOs: ArrayList<ContentDTO> = arrayListOf()

        init {
            firestore?.collection("images")?.addSnapshotListener {
                    querySnapshot, _ ->
                
                // Log.d("query", "working")
                // I can't see this log because the query doesn't work

                //Sometimes, this code return null of querySnapshot when it signout
                if (querySnapshot == null) return@addSnapshotListener

                // Get data
                for (snapshot in querySnapshot.documents) {
                    contentDTOs.add(snapshot.toObject(ContentDTO::class.java)!!)
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            // 화면 넓이의 1/2 크기의 정사각형 만들기
            var width = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2
            var imageView = ImageView(parent.context)
            imageView.layoutParams = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(width, width)
            return CustomViewHolder(imageView)
        }

        inner class CustomViewHolder(var imageview: ImageView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(imageview)

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return contentDTOs.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            var imageview = (holder as CustomViewHolder).imageview
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(contentDTOs[position].imageUri)
                .apply(RequestOptions().centerCrop()).into(imageview)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is there data in images collection?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Yes, there are. The prev version shows data well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In constructor of FeedRecyclerViewAdapter you reference `firestore` property of the outer class. You create an instance of this adapter (which in turn calls its constructor) in `onCreateView` before you initialize value of `firestore` property. Due to the safe call in `Adapter`s constructor you don't see any error, but `addSnapshotListener` is never called.

In kotlin, you should generally avoid this kind of weird initialization strategies. Why is `firestore` nullable? Is `firestore = null` a valid state of this class? Will `firestore` instance ever change? If you don't want to explicitly "detach" this object from Fragment instance (and I cannot see why would you want to in this case) you should use more idiomatic ways to initialize a property:

- initialization during construction: `private val firestore = ...`
- lazy initialization - when initialization should be deferred to first use of the property: `private val firestore by lazy { ... }`
- `lateinit` property - when you want to initialize value manually but using it before initialization is not valid: `private lateinit var firestore: Firestore`

Comment: God.. Thank you so much.. I feel silly. And I've changed the initialization strategy as you said. I should be more careful about this. Thanks again!